# iOS AutoLayout: I wonder set stackView's views View Priority. what is different by setting?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Hello :) I study UIStackView views priority.

[image: img1]

this picture is my current situation.
I put greenBtn, redBtn, yellowBtn in stackView.

I also set each button size.

GreenBtn width = 100, height = 100.

RedBtn width = 200, height = 300.

YellowBtn width = 250, height = 100.

And now StackView's.
Axis = Vertical, Alignment = Fill, Distribution = Fill.

And those has Conflicting Constraints about each width.
I want stackView width equal yellow Btn's width.

---

So first, I tried to modify each Btn Content Hugging Priority.

GreenBtn CH(Content Hugging)
Hori: 250
Verti: 250

RedBtn CH
Hori: 249
Verti: 250

YellowBtn CH
Hori: 248
Verti: 250

Not working,,,

---

So I also tried to change Compressing Resistance(CR) prioirty

GreenBtn CR
Hori: 750
Verti: 750

RedBtn CR
Hori: 751
Verti: 750

YellowBtn CR
Hori: 752
Verti: 750

Still not work ... StackView's width = 100

---

[image: img2]

Finally I tried to change each button's required Priority only. (each CHCR value setting defaultLow, defaultHigh)

GreenBtn width priority = 997

RedBtn width priority = 998

YellowBtn width priority = 999

and Now stackView's width has 250width( Yellow Btn width)

[image]

---

Question1. I wonder why doesn't changed stackView width when I changed CH value or CR value. what caused my settings to be wrong and how to fix it?

Question2. I wonder why changed when I change buttons required priority value?

If the required priority is the same as 1000, isn't CHCR applied differently depending on the priority value of CHCR? Is the required priority over .defaultLow and .defaultHigh value just the boss?

Thanks for reading the long question.

Comment: If you want stackView width 200 add constraint width=200 to stack view with higher priority . Suppress the fill on horizontal axis (I think it is alignment). To understand what you do the best is to suppress all constraints and add them back one by one and understand what they do. After you can use priority to resolve conflict knowing.

Comment: You want stack view width = yellow button width, but what about the horizontal position and width of the other buttons? You want them to be centred horizontally in the stack view and maintain the widths you set, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's understand *where* the conflict actually is.

The distribution of the stack view is set to "Fill". A "Fill" distribution in a vertical stack view means that the arranged subviews must extend all the way from very left of the stack view to the very right. In other words, **the subviews' widths must be equal to the stack view's width.**

This directly conflicts with the widths constraints of your buttons. The buttons cannot have widths 100, 200, 250, and at the same time, have the same width as the stack view. That would imply the buttons all have the same width.

Now onto your questions

> I wonder why doesn't changed stackView width when I changed CH value or CR value. what caused my settings to be wrong and how to fix it?

Content hugging and compression resistance is quite irrelevant here, as it is to do with *content*. The "content" of your buttons is the text "Button" inside them.

But the conflict here isn't caused by the button's content, so tinkering with them won't fix the conflict. The conflict is caused by the combination of the buttons' width constraints and the stack view's distribution, so you need to change/delete at least one of those things to fix the problem.

> I wonder why changed when I change buttons required priority value?

This is because the width constraints is actually where the conflict is. By making the width constraints lower-priority, you allow them to break, when there are higher priority constraints, such as those "stackView.leading = button.leading" and "stackView.trailing = button.trailing" constraints added by the "fill" distribution.

Assuming the layout you want is actually something like this:

[image]

You should set the distribution to "Center", not "Fill".

Comment: While studying CHCR, I was very confused, but thank you for letting me know clearly. In addition, thank you for letting us know that Center is a good solution rather than Fill.